# How to display data (which has just been inserted in database) in a TextView?

Tags: xamarin.android

The attached photo is a representation of my layout.I need to enter the first and last name in the EditTexts. And by pressing the Insert Button, the info is saved to the database. (This part I managed to do) However, on clicking the Show button, the entered input is to be displayed in the TextView which consists of the firstname & lastname. [Attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7RYf.png)

Comment: What database are you using, if you want to read table/value from db, it's important to know how did you create table/db. If you just want to combine the text in two `EditText`s to one then show them in `TextView`, it's very simple.

Comment: @Grace Feng -MSFT I'm using SQLite and the code below to create the table.`string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
 public bool CreateDatabase()
     { try
         {  using (var connection = new 
 SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Users.db")))
                {connection.CreateTable<User>();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
              Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }`

Comment: Try to read this doc: [Create a Database with SQLite.NET](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite-component/), the third part "To find the number of records in the database".

Answer (score 0):

to upload your data into remote database you can use this code

```
//enregistrement des donnees dans la base de donnees
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://test.com/login.php");
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

        parameters.Add("Email", email);
        parameters.Add("Password", password);
        client.UploadValuesCompleted += Client_UploadValuesCompleted;
        client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);
```

it will generate this method

```
private void Client_UploadValuesCompleted(object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result) == "success!!!")
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "success!!!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        else if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result) == "failed!!!")
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "failed!!!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
```

and to retrieve your data you can use code

```
articles = new JavaList<ModelArticle>();
        mWebClient = new WebClient();
        mUrl = new Uri(urlAddress);
        mWebClient.DownloadDataAsync("your url");
        mWebClient.DownloadDataCompleted += MWebClient_DownloadDataCompleted;
```

it will generate this method

```
    private void MWebClient_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
                articles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JavaList<ModelArticle>>(json);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, " Vueillez verifier votre connexion a internet puis reessayer ", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        });
    }
```

now your result is in the javalist articles don't forget to create a model of your json result

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i'm not using a web services